# Baby Born in the UK, parent on Tier 2 and Tier 4 Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa

I am on a Tier 2 ICT long term visa and my wife is on a student Tier 4 visa. We have a child born in the UK.

We are thinking of bringing him back to our home nation for a short trip and back to the UK come December 2016.

We will, however, stay in the UK until July 2017, when my wife has completed her studies and we will return to our country for good.

As such, it does not make sense for my child to apply for a dependent visa under Tier 2; he does not qualify to apply as a dependent under my wife's Tier 4 visa.

Since we and our child will effectively be in the UK for less than 6 months, is it possible for him to re-enter the UK with a visitor visa rather than applying for a dependent visa?

Thanks,
Lionel

Comment: I just don't know if it is plausible to believe that a young child is just there to 'visit' his parents. Furher, as your visa types could conceivably lead to longer term residence, even though that is not your intention, that might cause a situation, however unintentional by all parties, where the child might become an overstayer, something HO would like to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What will be the best way to solve this situation? Even if we do produce a return ticket for the child to leave 6 months later, will that be sufficient for the HO to buy into it? 
The main problem is there is no avenue to contact HO to ask about this sort of question, seems the only way is to seek help from immigration lawyer?

Comment: I'd say the best way is to get a Tier 2 dependent visa. If you do it now, you can probably have it all wrapped up well before December (I don't know for sure when you wanted to leave the UK, was guessing about the same time),